# Java / Wildfly: Threads piling up / Eclipse shows one additional running thread for each request

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, wildfly, threadpool

I am using javas `Thread` to connect via SMTP to our mailprovider as this can take some time until it finishes and I dont want the request to wait.

But it looks like the threads are not closed after they are finished.
I noticed this in the debug mode of Eclipse:

[image]

For each time I create a `new Thread()`, it adds one running thread, but it is not closing it (at least I assume this, as eclipse still shows `Running`).

This is my code:

```
             Thread mailThread = new Thread() {

                    public void run() {

                        System.out.println("Does it work?");

                        try {
                            Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
                            t.connect("user","pass");
                            t.sendMessage(message,message.getAllRecipients());
                            t.close();
                            System.out.println("SENT");
                            return;
                        } catch (MessagingException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                };

                mailThread.start();
```

Is this working as intended? Or does `Running` in eclipse mean something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not only to use the debugger to see, to see which threads you have at a certain point in time. Debuggers might display threads which are active during a break point but should not be there under normal conditions.

It is preferrable to use the command line tool *jstack* to create thread dumps. This will dump all the threads in a JVM at a certain point in time.

Here are some instructions on how to use it: https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/experience-manager/kb/TakeThreadDump.html

Another thing could help you debugging and finding threads in the dump: give threads a name using the string in one of the constructor.

```
new Thread("foo")
```

Then it becomes easier to find these in the thread dump.

If you call a thread "foo" then it will show up in a thread dump like this:

```
"foo" #16 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000041970800 nid=0x41f8 waiting on condition [0x000000004244e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(java.base@9/Native Method)
    at stackoverflow.ThreadReferenceTest$1.run(ThreadReferenceTest.java:14)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Service Thread" #15 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000041914000 nid=0x3d90 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

Comment: You should not be spawning new threads manually like this when using JavaEE. If you want to do things like send email without blocking, sends a message to a jms queue with an man that sends the email. You can then easily control the max number of smtp sessions and has the bonus that if your email server fails, the messages can sit on the queue awaiting retry.

Comment: Alternatively, just send your email to localhost and let your local mta deliver to the server you are trying to send to (smarthost)

Comment: @WillT: I agree that you should not be spawning threads like that in JavaEE. Also sending emails to localhost is a good idea.

Comment: It was indeed spawning a new process. @WillT @gil.fernandes we are implementing a queueing system, but this will take some time. I went with a Promise solution `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> this.send(session, message));` for now. That fixed it. Thank you guys!